# Create multiple line charts to display last 10 process order machine speed individually in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I want to display 10 multiple line charts which display last 10 process order machine speed for e.g. if I select machine name on slicer then display machine speed by timestamp but first line chart display machine speed by timestamp for last 1 process order and second line chart display machine speed by timestamp for 2 last process order and so on for 10 process order separately.

How can I do that in PowerBI?

- x-axis (timestamp)
- y-axis (machine speed)

Display multiple line chart to display each 10 process order machine speed in individual line chart
[image]

[image]

when i select machine name on slicer it display 4 line chart graph as mentioned above

Comment: Please add your sample data and expected output. That will make things easier to understand.

Comment: Review my post again I have added the screenshot i want

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text.

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text.

Comment: data not copied in text pls review my screenshots

Comment: Where is your machine name column in the sample data?

Comment: Equipment name is Machine name

Comment: Ok, when you select a Machine Name, You have 4 top Machine Speeds filtered out (as per my understanding). Now, why do you need a line chart? They are simply 4 different data for one category. Or do you want those 4 values to be shown as a line?

Comment: Another Q, where is your "x-axis (timestamp)"?